# How do I receive notification from UIImagePickerController that a Photo has been touched?

Tags: delegates, uiimagepickercontroller, nsnotifications

How do I receive notification from UIImagePickerController that a Photo has been touched?

I am using a SVProgresHUD which is best stopped in imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: 
 but where to start it?

What I need is is another delegate function notifying the app that the
 user has touched the photo of choice, so that the HUD can be started.

The UIImagePickerController using iPhone Photo Library is started from the main thread in my 
   findPhotoAction: 
 This is the last place in my code that I could start the ProgressHUD. It is wrong to start the HUD
 at that point. The user clicks through the following before actually touching the desired photo (which is the proper place to
 launch the ProgressHUD.

```
  Camera Roll item in picker's UITableView
  Touch Desired Photo
```

Can you please suggest a solution? Do I need a custom UIPickerController?

Thanks very much, Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found everything I needed from Ray Wenderlich

```
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1888/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-33
```

Thanks for reading.